# Vue 2.0 click event from inside component not registering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue app, which has a component in it that represents the whole page. Inside that component, I have another component which represents (for example) a menu. Inside that menu, I have a button with a @click handler that Vue is supposed to handle. However, that is not happening, and I'm going mad. Please help!

I have a blue bordered button that you are supposed to click for the EXPAND text to change. The components work just fine, and the text is rendered differently when I change the value of the 'expanded' property in the menu component. But I cannot get that value to change as a result of the click.

```js
Vue.component('vuemenu', {
 template: '#menu-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
     expanded: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
   expand: function() {
     this.expand = !this.expanded;
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('page', {
 template: '#page-template',
  methods: {
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
.expanded {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.clickme {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <page></page>
</div>

<template id="page-template">
  <div id="page">
  Here is the menu
    <vuemenu></vuemenu>
    And here is the rest of the page
  </div>
</template>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
<template id="menu-template">
  <div id="menu">
  Menu
  <div class="clickme" @click="expand">
  click
  </div>
  <div :class="{'expanded': expanded}">
    EXPAND
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `this.expand = !this.expanded;` should probably be `this.expanded = !this.expanded;`

Comment: Uh, yeah, shit. In my real-world scenario I don't have a typo and thought I had a simple reproduceable example here. Let's try again! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in this code

```
Vue.component('vuemenu', {
    template: '#menu-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
        expanded: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    expand: function() {
        this.expanded = !this.expanded; // this.expanded not this.expand
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('page', {
    template: '#page-template',
  methods: {
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah this was sloppy from me, and ultimately resulting in a pointless question. My real application does not have a similar typo, and in fact doesn't even have an event listener registered if I check out the element in chrome dev tools. This one in the example does, so I'll have to try something else to see if I can reproduce the scenario I'm actually facing rather than this one.

Comment: Okay, that is better